# PHP: Adobe Reader can't open PDF files created with fpdf

Tags: php, redirect, location, adobe, fpdf

I have generated pdf file using fpdf but i'm getting the error.
Adobe reader could not open the 'invoice.pdf' because it is either not a supported file type or because the file has been damaged. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
<?php 
$f_name=$_POST['first-name'];

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{   
$f_name=$_POST['name'];
$l_name=$_POST['last-name'];
$email=$_POST['email'];

require("fpdf/fpdf.php");
$fpdf=new FPDF();
$fpdf->AddPage();
$fpdf->setFont("Arial","B",16);
$fpdf->Cell(0,10,"Invoice",1,1,"C");
$fpdf->Cell(95,10,"Name:",1,0,"C");
$fpdf->Cell(95,10,$f_name,1,1,"C");
$fpdf->Cell(95,10,"Last Name:",1,0,"C");
$fpdf->Cell(95,10,$l_name,1,1,"C");
$fpdf->Cell(95,10,"Email:",1,0,"C");
$fpdf->Cell(95,10,$email,1,1,"C");

$file_location = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/invoice/up_pdfs/".$f_name.".pdf";
 file_put_contents($file_location,$fpdf); 

ob_clean(); 

$fpdf->output();
 header("Location: index.php");
 }
 ?>
```

Comment: `exit();` before `require("fpdf/fpdf.php");` and check is there any error in your logic? and check your `$_POST` values, may be there is an error.

Comment: @VipulSolanki, no error found..

Comment: then check `$f_name`,`$l_name`,`$email` and `require("fpdf/fpdf.php");` path if this is okey then try without file_location, like `file_put_contents($f_name.".pdf",$fpdf);`

Comment: @VipulSolanki, i have tried the form with ur suggestion. i'm getting the post values and the generated pdf not open

Comment: print this path`$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/invoice/up_pdfs/"` and check if it is correct then try with `$fpdf->Output($file_location,'F');`

Comment: and remove `file_put_contents($file_location,$fpdf);`

Comment: @VipulSolanki, thanks a lot.....its working.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `$fpdf->Output($file_location,'F');` and remove `file_put_contents($file_location,$fpdf);`

```
   if(isset($_POST['submit']))
   {   
   $f_name=$_POST['name'];
   $l_name=$_POST['last-name'];
   $email=$_POST['email'];

   require("fpdf/fpdf.php");
   $fpdf=new FPDF();
   $fpdf->AddPage();
   $fpdf->setFont("Arial","B",16);
   $fpdf->Cell(0,10,"Invoice",1,1,"C");
   $fpdf->Cell(95,10,"Name:",1,0,"C");
   $fpdf->Cell(95,10,$f_name,1,1,"C");
   $fpdf->Cell(95,10,"Last Name:",1,0,"C");
   $fpdf->Cell(95,10,$l_name,1,1,"C");
   $fpdf->Cell(95,10,"Email:",1,0,"C");
   $fpdf->Cell(95,10,$email,1,1,"C");

    $file_location = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/invoice/up_pdfs/".$f_name.".pdf";

    ob_clean(); 

    $fpdf->Output($file_location,'F');
    header("Location: index.php");
    }
?>
```